# Finding the first five terms of the power series of the function satisfying $4y''+xy' -2y=-3x$, $y(0)=20$, and $y'(0) = 3$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

> Can someone please help me solve the differential equation $$4y''+xy' -2y = -3x$$ where $y$ is expressed as a power series in $x$ around $x=0$ in the case that $y(0) = 20$ and $y'(0) = 3$. How do I find the first five terms of the power series?

I am having trouble understanding how to attack such a problem. Solving the differential through separation of variables is clear so far but I am not sure where to go from there.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Do you want the power series around $0$?

Comment: yes @user2628206

Comment: You can differentiate the defining equation $n$ times and use the product rule to deduce that $y^{2 + n}(x) = -\frac{1}{4} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n y^{(i)}(x) + xy^{(1 + n)}(x) +2y^{(n)}(x) 
 + 3x \cdot \delta_{0,n}\right) $ for $n \in \mathbb N_0$. One can then evaluate at $0$ and use the formula plus initial values  $y(0)$ and $y^\prime(0)$ to inductively get the value of $y^{n}(0)$ and thus compute all Taylor terms.

Comment: Additionally, if you already have an explicit solution by separation of variables, explicit differentiation of said function and evaluation of said derivatives at zero will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $x=0$ in the ODE to find $y''(0)$, i.e. $4y''(0)+0\cdot y'(0)-2y(0)=-3\cdot0 \implies y''(0)=\ldots$

Then differentiate again to find the third and fourth derivatives in terms of the previous derivatives, and substitute in zero each time.

The series solution is then
$$y(0)+y'(0)x+y''(0)\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\ldots+y^{(r)}(0)\dfrac{x^r}{r!}+\ldots$$

You mentioned you tried to solve it by separation of variables but this ODE can't be solved by separation of variables. To find a series solution, you should try the method I've given above.

Comment: so then y''(0) = 0? But if you differentiate again wouldn't you just end up with 0?

Comment: To confirm your answer, here's the complete answer:  $$-\frac{1}{32} \sqrt{\pi } \left(x^2+4\right) \left(12 \sqrt{2}-c_1
   \text{erfc}\left(\frac{x}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)\right)+\frac{c_2 x^2}{4}-\frac{c_1
   e^{-\frac{x^2}{8}} x}{8 \sqrt{2}}+c_2+3 x$$

Comment: @rudinsimons12 evaluating your O.D.E. at $0$ gives $4y^{\prime\prime}(0) - 2 \cdot 20 = 0$. Thusly, $y^{\prime\prime}(0) \neq 0 $

Comment: Exact solution $y=20+3x+5x^2$

Comment: Then I got 0s after third term

Comment: @rudinsimons12 What user2628206 says is correct, you should get $y''(0)=10$

Comment: @DavidG.Stork That doesn't look useful here, as some of the terms in your answer, such as the $\exp(-x^2/8)$, need to be expressed as series too to get the series solution!

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

$$y=20+3x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+...$$

$$xy'=3x+2a_2x^2+3a_3x^3+4a_4x^4+...$$

$$y''=2a_2+6a_3x+12a_4x^2+...$$

If we replace in the equation, we get

$$8a_2=40$$
$$24a_3+3-6=-3$$
$$48a_4+2a_2-2a_2=0$$

Answer (score 2):

The full solution is:

$$20 + x (3 + 5 x)$$

which has the obvious series expansion.